# how do social sites like Facebook using php keep their scripts checking for news feed without overloading the server?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, watch

Are they looping scripts or do they have some code on watch? How do they do it?

I'm looking for a tutorial to write a script so I can watch a database table for timestamp change, and when it changes, the code automatically grabs that row and echoes it.

Comment: I don't know that such a tutorial exists, but you might want to read up on websockets/long polling and message queuing

Comment: `the server` - facebook has more than just **ONE** server...

Comment: No matter how much resources and tools one has, if not used properly or to the right standard, they won't yield good results. So even if they have a lot of servers to even mirror their data, if they have mulconfigured databases, it's a waste.

Comment: I know Ffacebook uses NoSQL which has it's own advantages, That could be part of the answer.

Comment: Well, they bought friendfeed and also tornado framework. Despite it is a python framework, some php libraries exist do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Facebook depends on the user's browser (javascript timer) to pull the newsfeed every X seconds (think ajax). They also keep a cache of each user's feed.

Regarding performance, big Internet companies have huge horsepower to host their apps (think in several hundres of thousands of servers), but also they optimize, optimize and optimize again. Google created it's own webserver optimized to their needs, in Facebook's case, they developed their own database, called Cassandra, and then donated the source code to the Apache Foundation. Facebook also developed their own php compiler to convert php code into faster C++ native code called "[hiphop for php](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/)", wich is also freely available.

On the other hand, if your queries are optimized, your database indexes are fine tuned, and your dbms is configured to perform well there should not be a great performance impact for what you are requiring.